# What does "claimed her body" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_Lake#Death

> Lake died on July 7, 1973, of hepatitis and acute renal failure
>   (complications of her alcoholism) in Burlington, Vermont's Fletcher
>   Allen Hospital.[35][36] Her son, Michael, **claimed her body**.

What does "claimed her body" mean?

Comment: He asserted his right as next-of-kin to dispose of her physical remains.

Comment: @StoneyB "next-of-kin"? Could you explain that in a simple English? I am an English language learner not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Derfder It means either being a son, a daughter or adopted child. Which is first degree relative to the person. Note: In most countries adopted children doesn't count as next-of-kin. While in some countries with advanced laws counts.

Comment: As @BerkerYüceer says. "Next" is literally "nearest"; "kin" is "family", cognate with Latin *gens*; so *next-of-kin* is the person most closely related, as the law defines those relationships.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't get it at all. Does "claimed her body" mean to identify her body because he knows her the best, because he (her son) was her closest relative and he was well aware how she looks like so the body identification process was reliable and bullet-proof?

Comment: @Derfder No; the statement does not mean that he identified the body but that he claimed the right to decide what would be done with it - burial or cremation or donation to science or whatever - and by whom.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer, "next of kin" does not necessarily mean offspring. It could be a sibling, a parent, or a spouse, or even a cousin or grandparent - whoever is most closely related to the person in question. (Also, adopted children are legally absolutely no different from biological children. That's what "adopted" *means*.)

Comment: @Martha facepalm! I am sorry to be skeptical about this but i did not mean to offend anyone here! It's well known in some countries adopted children are not counting as biological children "in front of law". Off course adopted or not children is your "next-of-kin" but against some law it's not also meaning of "next-of-kin" here in this topic is her son. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_of_kin

Comment: @Martha and if you ask me there is no difference between biological and adopted children! Both ways they live with your education and love they are a part of you but when it comes to "claiming bodies" law comes up and says only closest relative has the right to decide.. Again in my opinion and as showed on Wikipedia aand enforced by laws "in some countries" children are the first degree relatives. That is what i intended to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Claiming" an object (like a body, or a lost item) means telling someone that it is yours. Claiming a body means that a relative or other person of someone who has died takes charge of the body for burial or cremation. This is usually done by the person's close relatives (spouse, children), but the person can also specify someone in her will to make the arrangements, or a government authority might do so in special cases.

This passage is saying that Veronica's son Michael went to the hospital and took her body away for the funeral.

Comment: Well, more likely it means that her son Michael arranged for a funeral home to take her body away for the funeral (our society tends to frown on people stuffing dead bodies into their vehicles). This probably involved Michael going to the hospital and filling out some paperwork, and going to the funeral home and filling out some paperwork and paying some money.